Use sms retriever api in viewmodel
I want to use Sms Retriver Api in view model, but in order to get a client object I should pass android context to getClient method like below.
val smsRetreiverClient = SmsRetriever.getClient(requireContext())

but the problem is that I want to keep my business code up to viewmodel layer. and injecting context into viewmodel is not considered good.
What should I do to avoid injecting context or implementing business code in ui layer?
Any suggestions an solutions will be much appreciated.

you are using hilt ?

@sasikumar no. koin.

The short answer to this is that you should utilise Dependency Injection to provide an instance of SmsRetreiverClient that has already been initialised with a Context.
The longer answer is that you should dedicate some time to learning the de facto way of doing this on Android which is by using the Hilt library.
You can find the official Google guide to this here.
This post has an example of creating a dependency with the ApplicationContext that you should also find useful.
Best of luck
